# Como puedo solucionar este error de git?

Tags: html, visual-studio, css3, git, github

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
trato de solucionar esto pero no encuentro la manera, alguna forma a traves de la terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando utilizas el comando "git config --global alan" este accede al archivo ".gitconfig" que en windows usualmente se encuentra en C:\Users%tu nombre de usuario%.gitconfig

Ese archivo es muy parecido a un json por ejemplo

[image: Imagen archivo .gitconfig]

user, init, core, etc son las "key"

Como observarás no existe la key "alan".

En caso de que quieras cambiar algo del archivo debes usar el comando

```
git config --global user.name "El nombre entre estas comillas"
```

El comando anterior cambia el nombre de usuario, también puedes cambiar

user.email
user.username

y más.

[Lista de Keys del archivo .gitconfig](https://gist.github.com/pksunkara/988716)

Comment: gracias por el aporte, voy a probar con esta forma no tenia conocimiento de aquello